How to properly transform a JSON input using JOLT when handling both accepts_marketing and email_marketing_consent fields?
I am working with a JOLT transformation that takes an input JSON object and converts it into a new structure, but I need to handle the cases where both accepts_marketing and email_marketing_consent exist in the input or when only one of them is available.
Input JSON Example:
{
  "email": "john.calvert@nm.com",
  "first_name": "John",
  "accepts_marketing": false,
  "email_marketing_consent": {
    "state": "not_subscribed",
    "opt_in_level": "single_opt_in",
    "consent_updated_at": null
  }
}

Expected Output:
{
  "optin_newsletter": false,
  "email": "john.calvert@nm.com",
  "first_name": "John"
}

Current JOLT Transformation:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accepts_marketing": "optin_newsletter",
      "email_marketing_consent": {
        "state": {
          "subscribed": {
            "#true": "optin_newsletter"
          },
          "*": {
            "#false": "optin_newsletter"
          }
        }
      },
      "email": "email",
      "first_name": "first_name"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "subscribed": "=toBoolean"
    }
  }
]


Problem:

When both accepts_marketing and email_marketing_consent are present in the input, the output for optin_newsletter is becoming an array: [ false, "false" ], but I want it to be a simple false value.

When only one of the fields (accepts_marketing or email_marketing_consent) is present in the input, I want the output to reflect just that value without duplication or errors.


Questions:
1. How can I handle the case where both accepts_marketing and email_marketing_consent are present, and I only want a single boolean value for optin_newsletter (not an array of values)?
2. If only accepts_marketing or only email_marketing_consent is present, how can I ensure the transformation produces the correct value for optin_newsletter?
3. How can I modify my JOLT spec to conditionally use one of these fields or prioritize one over the other if both are available?
Additional Details:
The goal is for the optin_newsletter field to always be a boolean value (either true or false), even when both fields (accepts_marketing and email_marketing_consent) are present.
I am trying to convert email_marketing_consent.state values like "subscribed" and "not_subscribed" into booleans (true and false, respectively) for consistency.

See if the following spec will work:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "email": "&",
      "first_name": "&",
      "email_marketing_consent": {
        "state": {
          "subscribed": {
            "#true": "option_newsletter"
          },
          "*": {
            "#false": "option_newsletter"
          }
        }
      },
      "accepts_marketing": "option_newsletter"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "option_newsletter": "ONE"
    }
  },

  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "option_newsletter": "=toBoolean"
    }
  }

]


Hello @samsal77
It worked with the input I have shared. But not working when accepts_marketing is not present in input and Its not working when email_marketing_consent.state.subscribed.

Hi, I have updated the jolt spec above. I think I forgot to have the # before the true default value for subscribed state. Regarding how you prioritize which value to use if both are present , since cardinality spec is used to switch from Array to One it will always take the first element, therefore the order in the first spec is very important and whatever comes first will have the priority. In my jolt since email_marketing_consent comes first it will be prioritized over accepts_marketing.

Worked like a charm!
Thank you so much.
